# group by function apply on date in sql

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to apply a groupBy query on the date (year wise)
the issue is I have only one column of date which store date like this 2010-11-01
i want to make group of only year

Comment: I think this question needs more detail. What have you tried, what is the format of the data, what exactly is it that is giving you trouble?

Comment: you need to create new column which have year number in sql then you can apply group

Comment: `->select('year(date) as year)->groupBy('year')` somthing like this

Comment: Use GROUP BY YEAR(yourDate)

Comment: I don't want to add a column 
if there was an extra column than it was easy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database is properly designed to have the date column as a date type.
You should group by the `YEAR()` value of the date value.

Call  the `groupBy()` method and pass in the raw sql `YEAR(your_date_column_name)`.

```
->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(your_date_column_name)')
```